# Помощь по интерфейсу Visual Studio 2019

Tags: отладка

Начал работать с отладкой, и необходимо эти два окна при ее вызове. Как их настроить и каким сочетанием клавиш вызвать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: брейк поинт мб сначала в коде поставить?

Comment: Вероятно зависимость здесь диаметрально противоположна. Для этих окон необходимо запустить дебагер.